# Error printing from 16-bit applications in Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm having problems trying to run a bunch of old 16-bit applications in Windows 2008 Server.
The applications ran fine up to Windows 2003 Server, but when I try to print from any of
them, all show printing errors (Unable to create printer driver / TERM error / etc)

- The LPT1 port is redirected to a shared printer via NET USE LPT1 \ServerName\SharedPrinter
- DIR > LPT1 (or any shell redirection to the printer) is working fine.
- I'm using an Administrator account, so it shouldn't be a permissions problem, right?

To reproduce the behavior, I made a small test program in C (TCC 1.01 for DOS). It runs fine
in XP / 2003 Server, but on 2008 Server it shows the handle opening (5) but when is trying
to write in that handle, issues an error (Write fault error writing device LPT1, Abort, Retry,
Ignore, Fail)

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>

int main(void)
{
 int handle, status;
 char* sbuff;

 handle = open("LPT1", O_WRONLY, S_IFBLK);
 printf("%d\n", handle);

 if (!handle)
 {
    printf("open failed\n");
    exit(1);
 }

 sbuff = "[print test]\n";
 write(handle, sbuff, strlen(sbuff));

 close(handle);
 getch();

 return 0;
}
```

Any clues?

TIA,
Pablo

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit Windows 2008?

Comment: I'm guessing 32 bit, since 64-bit Win2008 won't run 16 bit applications **at all**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t638754-printing-from-dos-applications-lpt1-to-usb-attached-printer-in-vista.html) solves your problem. Key step is to use printer pooling instead of net use.

> 2) Open Printer properties (in Vista, open as Administrator)
>
> 3) Turn on "printer pooling" (under Ports tab)
>
> 4) In addition to whatever is already selected (for example, USB), also
>   select "LPT1:"
>
> 5) Click apply

Comment: If that doesn;t work, a workaround exists by using Printfil http://www.printfil.com/english.htm to print from your DOS app.